# How to wrap text around a textbox which overlays a table with multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I wrap text around a textbox or image which overlays a table with multiple columns?

[image]

Comment: just for clarification, does the picture show input or expected output? what have you tried so far (e.g. what happens if you place textbox and set text to wrap around it)?

Comment: it shows desired output (as answer bellow). i have done this example by simple line breaking which is not the best way:). The problem is that you can place textbox only into the one column and not over multiple columns..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can't place a text box over a table border AND wrap text around

Workaround: Create two additional text boxes and place them beneath your original one

- First text box is placed under the original content text box in the left column. As position style choose *Clear*
- Second text box is also placed under the original content text box. But in the right column. As position style choose *Clear* again
- Select your content text box and choose *Bring to front*
- Align all three text boxes properly as shown below

Tip: Via *Select » Select objects* you can select all three text boxes for easier copy&paste. (But you cannot *group* them)

[image][image]